# How to lock down a generic type which is an enum

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have a problem locking down a generic type. Below is an interface that is implemented by two enum classes. The `Cover` class is using a generic type, which is specified in a `CarRequest` class. I want to be able to use only the enums that implement the `CoverType` interface.

At first I thought of using an abstract class that is extended by the enums and use:

```
public class Cover<T extends AbstractCoverType>
```

But that does not work, because I cannot extend an enum class. Than I thought of the interface solution that is presented below, however in that case I cannot do:

```
public class Cover<T implements CoverType>
```

How can I lock down the `Cover` class to only accept as a generic type the first two enums and not the third?

Interface:

```
public interface CoverType {}
```

First enum:

```
public enum FireCoverType implements CoverType {
    SANITATION, RENTAL, GLASS
}
```

Second enum:

```
public enum CarCoverType implements CoverType {
    ACCESSORIES, LEGAL_ASSISTANCE
}
```

Third enum:

```
public enum PaymentTerm {
    MONTH, QUARTER, YEAR
}
```

Cover class:

```
public class Cover<T> {
    private T coverType;
    // getter and setter
}
```

CarRequest:

```
public class CarRequest {
    private Cover<CarCoverType> cover;
    // getter and setter
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `extends` when binding your generic type definition, regardless of whether it's an class or an interface.

In other words, there's no `implements` in generic type upper-binding - `extends` works for both classes and interfaces.

So:

`public class Cover<T extends CoverType>`

... is the solution you're looking for, where `CoverType` is the interface your enums implement.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html):

> Note that [...] `extends` is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces).

Also worth noting, `enum`s can't extend classes, as they implicitly extend [java.lang.Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) already.

Comment: Sometimes, the answer can be really simple. Thanks for saving me!